# How is this expression evaluated?

Tags: haskell

I am reading Real World Haskell and i can not understand when is the result of the `break`  method evaluated.
If it starts with the `pre:case suf of` clause then it has to go in the let clause fetch the tuple that  `break` method generates  and then treat the case expression?
Or how does it do it?

```
splitLines [] = []
splitLines cs = 
  let (pre, suf) = break isLineTerminator cs
  in pre : case suf of
            ('\r':'\n':rest) -> splitLines rest 
            ('\r':rest)      -> splitLines rest
            ('\n':rest)      -> splitLines rest
            _            -> []

isLineTerminator c = c == '\r' || c == '\n'
```

Is it :

- 1.Goes into `pre:case suf of`
- 2.Goes to let clause determines what `pre` and `suf` are
- 3.glues up `pre` and `suf` and then treats the case expression?

Or what is the order for constructing the case expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, all Haskell functions are defined using *a single expression* (at least, if you ignore `do` syntax). Contrary to statement-based languages like the C family, a function is just an expression.

Sometimes, though, it can enhance readability if you can break up a function definition in two or more sub-steps. Haskell's `let...in` syntax enables you to do that.

`let` lets you define one or more names that you can then reference in the `in` expression. You can define as many names as you want in the `let` part, but the `in` part must still be a single expression.

Another option is to use `where`. You can rewrite the `splitLines` function using `where` syntax instead:

```
splitLines [] = []
splitLines cs =
  pre : case suf of
          ('\r':'\n':rest) -> splitLines rest 
          ('\r':rest)      -> splitLines rest
          ('\n':rest)      -> splitLines rest
          _            -> []
  where (pre, suf) = break isLineTerminator cs

isLineTerminator c = c == '\r' || c == '\n'
```

In both cases, the expression of `splitLines` *conses* `pre` unto the expression starting with `case suf of`.

In order to be able to do that, it'll first have to evaluate `pre` and `suf`, which are both defined by the expression `break isLineTerminator cs`. So, in order to evaluate `pre` and `suf`, the overall function evaluates `break isLineTerminator cs`.

It now knows what `pre` and `suf` is, so it can evaluate the rest of the `case` expression and cons the result of that with `pre`.

Notice that `splitLines` is recursive, so this'll keep on happening until `splitLines` hits the base case `[]`.

Recall that Haskell is lazily evaluated, so all of this only happens just-in-time, when a result is required.

Comment: No. You don’t need to evaluate `pre` and `suf` to do the cons.  That would be wrong.  You won’t even call `break`.

Comment: So the let clause can be evaluated whenever it is needed?

Comment: @augustss Assuming you're in GHCi and evaluate `splitLines "foo\nbar"`, would you still say that `break` isn't called?

Comment: Yes, it can and will be evaluated when needed.  The pattern matching in `let` and `where` is a bit subtle; it doesn’t happen until one of the variables in the pattern is needed.

Comment: If you evaluate that expression in ghci, of course `break` is called.  The top level uses `print` which will fully evaluate. But if you type `null $ splitLines “a\nb”` then `break` is not called.  It all depends on how you use the result of `splitLines`.

Comment: @augustss I understand that, which is also why I wrote in my answer that Haskell is lazily evaluated. Based on the question, it seemed to me, however, that it would be more helpful to lead with how typical evaluation would proceed.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian The `let`-bound symbols are also lazily evaluated expressions, so they're evaluated when they're needed.

Comment: But the typical evaluation does not proceed as you explained.  Not unless you’ve compiled a very special purpose version for a strict context.

Comment: Assuming we have done the top level pattern match, and determined that it is a cons, the function will return at once with a cons of two thunks.  The caller might then evaluate these thunks if they are needed.

Comment: You can trust me on this, I’m one of the two people who invented compiled graph reduction, which is what ghc uses (back around 1981-1982). :)

Comment: @augustss I *do* trust you on that, and I upvoted your answer. What I tried to do with my answer was to explain things in terms that a Haskell beginner would find useful. Whether or not I succeeded in that, I'll let the community decide.

Comment: I'd say the exception to "all Haskell functions are defined using a single expression" is `where`, not `do`.

Answer (score 7):

It’s impossible to say how it’s evaluated unless you specify how the result of `splitLines` is going to be used.  Lazy evaluation does as little as possible. E.g., if you test the result with `null` then `break` is never called.  If you take the head and use that, `break` is called, but the `case` is never evaluated. And so on.